# How can I detect if jQuery lightslider has been instantiated, and how to clear instance if yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using [JQuery lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/). It works pretty well (well, actually, I had to jig the code a little bit, but enough of that for now).

What I am trying to achieve is to dynamically replace the lightSlider content with ajax return data, and this I can do.

With each new data set, I call the lightSlider plugin again. This is the "success" or "done" section of my ajax function:

```
        var lightsliderstring = "";
        for(i=1;i<thumbsArray.length;i++){
            lightsliderstring     += "<li>\n";
            if( $("#as_feature").val() ){
                lightsliderstring     += "   <h3>" + $("#as_feature").val() + " photo " + i + "</h3>\n";
            }
            lightsliderstring     += "   <img src=\"/" + thumbsArray[i] + "\" />\n";
            lightsliderstring     += "</li>\n";
        }

        $("#lightSlider").html(lightsliderstring);

        $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
            auto: true,
            gallery: false,
            item: 1,
            loop: true,
            slideMargin: 0,
            thumbItem: 0
        });
```

I call lightSlider again, with each new ajax call, because calling lightSlider only once doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's because the content is dynamically created after the DOM is loaded? Anyway, what I would like to do is clear the lightSlider function after each ajax call, because I think they are piling up on each other in the same div.

After one lightSlider call, it looks good:

[image: single instance of lightSlider]

But on my second ajax call, when lightSlider is instantiated again, it starts to "stack". Notice the doubled-arrows, vertically misaligned, and also the vertically doubling of the index dots below the picture:

[image: what my lightSlider container looks like after a second call]

What would cure this is some way to clear the first instance of lightSlider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a newer version of lightslider than 1.1.3 you should be able to .destroy() the existing instance as follows:

```
var slider = $('#lightslider').lightSlider();
slider.destroy();
```

For safety, you will need to check the slider is something before you call the destroy method though!

Comment: Two things: 1) I get the error "lightslider()...destroy is not a function. 2) The part about how to check that slider is something is one of the things I want to do. Can that be done by using typeof slider ?

Comment: Ignore my first error, that was the result of ignoring the case sensitivity of the container. id. Now I don't get a "destroy is not a function" error, but it seems to have done nothing to fix my original problem.

Comment: I can only assume that it's not clearing the existing HTML from the document in that case.  Having looked at the examples on an associated site: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html, it would appear destroy in fact leaves your <LI> elements intact.  So it looks like you need to clear the html first, perhaps with $('#lightslider').empty()

Comment: I nested the `<ul id="lightSlider">...</ul>` block within a `<div id="carousel-container">...</div>` block. Then, with each new form submission, I deleted the entire #lightSlider block with a `$("#carousel-container").html('');` Then I dynamically re-created the entire `<ul id="lightSlider">...</ul>` with the new, updated content. This works, and it's not really that much trouble. lightSlider looks good, works very good, very useful, and thank you!

Comment: what is the best way to use lighslider with ajax data is it to have an exiting ul element in the dom empty and populate with data with each ajax request or to have the lighslider element (ul) created and appended to a div ?

Answer (score 0):

The `$("#lightSlider").empty()` or `$("#lightSlider").html('')` didn't work for some reason. The lightslider instances continued to pile up with every new form submission. I don't know why. Neither did the `("#lightSlider").lightslider().destroy()` method seem to work, and that could be for some odd reason that I can't pinpoint, maybe something to do with the way I'm manipulating the DOM, I don't know.

What finally worked was to nest the `<ul id="lightSlider">...</ul>` block within a `<div id="carousel-container">...</div>` block. Then, with each new form submission, I deleted the entire #lightSlider block with a `$("#carousel-container").html('');` Then I dynamically re-created the entire `<ul id="lightSlider">...</ul>` with the new, updated content. Here's the working code:

```
        $("#carousel-container").html('');
        var lightsliderstring = "<ul id=\"lightSlider\">";
        for(i=1;i<thumbsArray.length;i++){
            lightsliderstring     += "<li>\n";
            if( $("#as_feature").val() ){
                lightsliderstring     += "   <h3>" + $("#as_feature").val() + " photo " + i + "</h3>\n";
            }
            lightsliderstring     += "   <img src=\"/" + thumbsArray[i] + "\" />\n";
            lightsliderstring     += "</li>\n";
        }
        lightsliderstring += "</ul>\n";

        $("#carousel-container").html(lightsliderstring);

        $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
            auto: true,
            gallery: false,
            item: 1,
            loop: true,
            slideMargin: 0,
            thumbItem: 0
        });
```

Comment: Did you look at the DOM after initializing lightSlider? It creates 2 wrapper elements around the element you call it on - emptying your original element's HTML leaves the wrappers in place. Calling `.lightSlider` again then creates new wrapper elements; using the `destroy` method instead should clean these up.